# Except in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException-part2

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

**I changed my code as Dan suggested** i can compile the program now, however, whatever the input is, the result is always 2. i put the second part of this program below the new code. please help.

Here's the NEW code.

```
    public class VowelCons 
        {
    private final String str;
    private final int totalConsonants;
    private final int totalVowels;

        public VowelCons(final String s) 
    {
             this.str = s;
                int totalConsonants = 0;
                int totalVowels = 0;
                if (null != s) 
        {
                    for (final char c : s.toCharArray()) 
            {
                                switch (c) 
                    {
                                        case 'A':
                                        case 'a':
                                        case 'E':
                                        case 'e':
                                        case 'I':
                                        case 'i':
                                        case 'O':
                                        case 'o':
                                        case 'U':
                                        case 'u':

                        totalVowels++;
                                            break;

                        default:

                        if (Character.isLetter(c)) 
                        {
                                                    totalConsonants++;
                                            }
                                            break;
                                    }
                        }
                }
            this.totalConsonants = totalConsonants;
            this.totalVowels = totalVowels;
        }


    public String getString() 
    {
             return str;
    }

    public int getNumConsonants() 
    {
                return this.totalConsonants;
    }

    public int getNumVowels() 
    {
                return this.totalConsonants;
    }
}
```

there's another part of this program which gets the user's input and passes it to this class.
Here's the code. [**this part cannot be changed according to the regulations**]

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class VowelConsCounter
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
         String input;        // User input
         char selection;      // Menu selection

         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
         input = keyboard.nextLine();

         VowelCons vc = new VowelCons(input);

        do
        {
          selection = getMenuSelection();

          switch(Character.toLowerCase(selection))
          {
            case 'a' :  System.out.println("\nNumber of vowels: " +
                        vc.getNumVowels());
                        break;
            case 'b' :  System.out.println("\nNumber of consonants: " +
                        vc.getNumConsonants());
                        break;
            case 'c' :  System.out.println("\nNumber of vowels: " +
                        vc.getNumVowels());
                        System.out.println("Number of consonants: " +
                        vc.getNumConsonants());
                        break;
            case 'd' :  System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
                        input = keyboard.nextLine();
                        vc = new VowelCons(input);
         }

      } while (Character.toLowerCase(selection) != 'e');

   }

   public static char getMenuSelection()
   {
      String input;     
      char selection;   

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("a) Count the number of vowels in the string.");
      System.out.println("b) Count the number of consonants in the string.");
      System.out.println("c) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string.");
      System.out.println("d) Enter another string.");
      System.out.println("e) Exit the program.");

      input = keyboard.nextLine();
      selection = input.charAt(0);

      while (Character.toLowerCase(selection) < 'a' || Character.toLowerCase(selection) > 'e')
      {
         System.out.print("Only enter a, b, c, d, or e: ");
         input = keyboard.nextLine();
         selection = input.charAt(0);
      }

      return selection;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because you are not initializing the instance variable `result`.

I would recommend using the following:

```
public class VowelCons {
    private final String str;
    private final int totalConsonants;
    private final int totalVowels;

    public VowelCons(final String s) {
        this.str = s;
        int totalConsonants = 0;
        int totalVowels = 0;
        if (null != s) {
            for (final char c : s.toCharArray()) {
                switch (c) {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'I':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'O':
                    case 'o':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'u':
                        totalVowels++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
                            totalConsonants++;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        this.totalConsonants = totalConsonants;
        this.totalVowels = totalVowels;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return str;
    }

    public int getTotalConsonants() {
        return this.totalConsonants;
    }

    public int getTotalVowels() {
        return this.totalConsonants;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (null == str ? "" : str) + " [consonants=" + totalConsonants + ", vowels=" + totalVowels + "]";
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (final String arg : args) {
            final VowelCons vc = new VowelCons(arg);
            System.out.println(vc.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This would, for example, output:

```
$ java VowelCons foo BaR "Lady GODIVA"
foo [consonants=1, vowels=2]
BaR [consonants=2, vowels=1]
Lady GODIVA [consonants=6, vowels=4]
```

Here are some points this example should help you learn:

1. Local variables may hide instance variables (see [[1]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [[2]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)).
2. Use `this` to reference instance variables (see [[1]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)). You should always reference instance variables using `this`, which prevents accidentally hiding it when you make future code changes and allows IDEs to provide context sensitive suggestions that only contain instance members.
3. Handle `null` `String`s passed to the constructor.
4. Use `switch` to simplify the logic and reduce redundant code in `if-else` logic.
5. Check for lower-case and upper-case vowels.
6. Ignore non-alphabetic characters in the vowel/consonant counts.
7. Implement a custom `toString()`.

Comment: Thank you gurus. I changed a lot of my codes. since there's another part of this program which will pass the user string to this class, i can't change much of the return result. anyhow, i used Dan's suggestion to rewrite the VowelCons class. but whatever i input, the result is 2. would like to know why, thanks gurus.

Comment: Sorry mates, my mistake. just because a typo the program didn't work. but now i fix it. it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are initialising the local array `result`, but then trying to read from the member array `result`. Since you haven't initialised the member one, it's still `null`, hence the `java.lang.NullPointerException` you're seeing.

You probably want to change `countVowelsAndCons` to have a `void` return type, and get rid of the local `result`. Then you need to make sure to call it before trying to call `getNumVowels` or `getNumConsonants`. Incidentally, things like `index` should be local variables within your member functions - they don't belong at class scope.

But more importantly, this probably shouldn't even be a class. You probably want something like:

```
private static boolean isVowel(char c)
{
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}

public static int countConsonants(String s)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0, len=s.length(); i<len; ++i)
    {
        if(!isVowel(s.charAt(i))) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

public static int countVowels(String s)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0, len=s.length(); i<len; ++i)
    {
        if(isVowel(s.charAt(i))) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```